# Как можно улучшить метод загрузки данных из БД?

Tags: java, android, sql

Есть БД с таблицами "books" , "books_authors", "authors". "books_authors" используется для отображения отношения многие ко многим. Нужно получить из базы список книг, внутри которых будут авторы. Вот как я это делаю:

```
public ArrayList<Book> getBooks() {
    Cursor booksCursor = mDB.rawQuery(TOP_SALES_BOOKS_QUERY, null);

    ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    if(booksCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int idIndex = booksCursor.getColumnIndex(Book.ID_TAG);
        int nameIndex = booksCursor.getColumnIndex(Book.NAME_TAG);
        //...

        do {
            int bookId = booksCursor.getInt(idIndex);
            String bookName = booksCursor.getString(nameIndex);
            //...

            Cursor authorsBooksCursor = mDB.rawQuery(AUTHORS_BY_BOOK_ID_QUERY,
                    new String[] {String.valueOf(bookId)});
            ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();
            if(authorsBooksCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int authorNameIndex = authorsBooksCursor.getColumnIndex(Author.NAME_TAG);

                do {
                    String authorName = authorsBooksCursor.getString(authorNameIndex);
                    authors.add(new Author(authorName));

                } while (authorsBooksCursor.moveToNext());
            }

            authorsBooksCursor.close();

            books.add(new Book(bookId, bookName, authors, ...));
        } while (booksCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    booksCursor.close();

    return books;
}
```

Метод выполняется ~40 секунд. Если же не получать authorsBooksCursor, то ~1 секунда. Как можно улучшить метод или запрос, для более быстрого его выполнения?

Вот сами запросы:

```
String TOP_SALES_BOOKS_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + Book.TABLE_NAME;

String AUTHORS_BY_BOOK_ID_QUERY = "SELECT BAT." + DEFAULT_ID_TAG + ", AT."
            + Author.NAME_TAG + " FROM " + BOOKS_AUTHORS_TABLE_NAME
            + " AS BAT INNER JOIN " + Author.TABLE_NAME + " AS AT ON BAT." + Author.ID_TAG +
            " = AT." + Author.ID_TAG + " WHERE BAT." + Book.ID_TAG + " = ?";
```

Comment: Можно тексты запросов TOP_SALES_BOOKS_QUERY и AUTHORS_BY_BOOK_ID_QUERY? Как правило лучше делать всё в одном запросе.

Comment: сделайте запрос к `books_authors`, отсортируйте по названию книги, и добавляйте в книгу авторов последовательно. Так будет один запрос.

Comment: @iksuy добавил.

Comment: Делайте один запрос с двойным джойном

Comment: @Etki, не сильно пойму, какой тогда я курсор получу? В котором будет примерно такие стоки(автор 1, книга 1;автор 2, книга 1;автор 3, книга 2;автор 4, книга 2;...)?

Comment: @metalurgus вы тоже имеете ввиду использовать двойной джойн? books_authors содержит только book_id и author_id

Comment: да, двойной джоин.

Comment: @metalurgus Получается нужно в цикле смотреть, если book_id  не изменился, добавляем нового автора? То вся инфа о книге будет повторятся, если если авторов более 1-го.

Comment: @metalurgus С таким подходом можно вообще все вопросы по оптимизации позакрывать. Вопрос поставлен корректно. Подробно. Да, пути решения могут быть разные, но это же не значит, что надо закрывать все вопросы, на которые нет однозначного ответа в википедии. И ваше предложение по Map мне кажется как раз "объективно верным ответом". Я бы даже предложил вам его как ответ опубликовать, добавив немного кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Map<Integer, Book> booksMap = new HashMap<>();

...

//Запрос
String query = "SELECT ba.book_id, b.name, a.name   
FROM books_authors ba 
INNER JOIN authors a ON ba.author_id = a.id
INNER JOIN books b ON ba.book_id = b.id"

...

//Заполнение

if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

    do {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        Book book = booksMap.get(id);
        if(book == null) {
            book = new Book();
            book.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            booksMap.put(id, book);
        }

        String authorName = cursor.getString(2);
        book.addAuthor(authorName);

    } while (authorsBooksCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Писал на коленке. Идею выразил, но не факт, что скомпилится. Запрос написал образно, подставьте свои названия в него.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!